# Display d3.js visualisation in Jupyter Lab

Tags: jupyter-lab

I would like to display a d3.js visualisation in Jupyter Lab/JupyterLab.  I have been following various web tutorials like [this one](https://www.stefaanlippens.net/jupyter-custom-d3-visualization.html) which often begin

```
%%javascript
require.config({
    paths: {
        d3: 'https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min'
    }
});
```

This works in Jupyter Notebook, but in Jupyter Lab I get:

```
Javascript Error: require is not defined
```

How can display a d3.js visualisation in Jupyter Lab?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This functionality was added by the Jupyter Lab javascript extension (which is installed by default).  You can see a demo notebook [here](https://gist.github.com/gnestor/f1893e0226ced227e910f11b769adc06).

The relevant bits are as follows. To add `d3.js` you need:

```
%%javascript
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.js';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    console.log(window.d3)
```

and then the following should work:

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
svg_script = '''
var svg = d3.select(element)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300);    

svg.append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "cyan")
    .attr("r", 130)
    .attr("cx", 150)
    .attr("cy", 150)
    .transition()
        .delay(100)
        .duration(10000)  
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("cx", 150)
        .style("fill", "blue"); 
'''

Javascript(svg_script)
```

Comment: The behaviours for adding javascript are different from jupyter-lab (IDE) and jupyter notebook (classic). Is there a solution for both ?